# How to log custom index table index_event with method logEvent()

Tags: magento-1.9, indexing

I want to add a entry to the table "index_event" via `Mage_Index_Model_Indexer`'s Method `logEvent`.

The custom indexer is from a 3rd party module called GroupsCatalog2 by Vinai (Link: https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2) and we want to utilize it with the Hackathon module AsyncIndex (Link: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/AsyncIndex).

Problem is, that AsyncIndex does not recognize the index of the groupscatalog2 module has to be rebuild and therefore is being ignored. But the groupscatalog2 module uses its own index tables and works with it.

I am now trying to patch the groupscatalog2 module to have it write the changes (or anything) to the magento index table aswell so AsyncIndex may pick it up.

Progress:

```
/**
     * Adds the to be reindex data also to the magento table 'index_events'
     *
     * @var $chunked array
     */
    private function insertToMagentoIndexTable($chunked)
    {
        //Create dummy model, either catalog or product model
        $entity = str_replace('_', '/', $this->_getEntityTypeCode());
        /** @var $dummyModel Mage_Catalog_Model_Product | Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
        $dummyModel = Mage::getModel($entity);

        /** @var $indexer Mage_Index_Model_Indexer */
        $indexer = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer');
        $processTable = $this->getTable('index/process_event');

        foreach ($chunked as $chunkData) {
            $entityId = $chunkData['catalog_entity_id'];

            $dummyModel->setId($entityId);

//            $indexer->logEvent($dummyModel, $this->_mainTable, 'save');
            $indexer->logEvent($dummyModel, $dummyModel->getResource()->getType(), Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE, FALSE);


            $x = 1;
        }
    }
```

which I added to the method ``_insertIndexRecordsIfMinChunkSizeReached``` of the groupscatalog2 module. (Right after the module will repopulate its own index tables)

The logEvent() call is the problem here as I dont really understand what I can throw at it to have it working.

Any suggestions?